# How can I compute percentage similarity between two images?

Tags: opencv, similarity

I have written a code snippet to compute structural similarity index (SSIM), pixel similarity, sift features to measure similarity, and earth movers distance between two images. I would like to find percentage similarity using these four metrics combined.

I tried the average of all the values from the metrics and convert them into percentages. But I am extremely doubtful of the approach

```
import warnings
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
from skimage.transform import resize
from scipy.stats import wasserstein_distance
from scipy.misc import imsave
from scipy.ndimage import imread
import numpy as np
import cv2

##
# Globals
##

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

# specify resized image sizes
height = 2**10
width = 2**10

##
# Functions
##

def get_img(path, norm_size=True, norm_exposure=False):
  '''
  Prepare an image for image processing tasks
  '''
  # flatten returns a 2d grayscale array
  img = imread(path, flatten=True).astype(int)
  # resizing returns float vals 0:255; convert to ints for downstream tasks
  if norm_size:
    img = resize(img, (height, width), anti_aliasing=True, preserve_range=True)
  if norm_exposure:
    img = normalize_exposure(img)
  return img


def get_histogram(img):
  '''
  Get the histogram of an image. For an 8-bit, grayscale image, the
  histogram will be a 256 unit vector in which the nth value indicates
  the percent of the pixels in the image with the given darkness level.
  The histogram's values sum to 1.
  '''
  h, w = img.shape
  hist = [0.0] * 256
  for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
      hist[img[i, j]] += 1
  return np.array(hist) / (h * w) 


def normalize_exposure(img):
  '''
  Normalize the exposure of an image.
  '''
  img = img.astype(int)
  hist = get_histogram(img)
  # get the sum of vals accumulated by each position in hist
  cdf = np.array([sum(hist[:i+1]) for i in range(len(hist))])
  # determine the normalization values for each unit of the cdf
  sk = np.uint8(255 * cdf)
  # normalize each position in the output image
  height, width = img.shape
  normalized = np.zeros_like(img)
  for i in range(0, height):
    for j in range(0, width):
      normalized[i, j] = sk[img[i, j]]
  return normalized.astype(int)


def earth_movers_distance(path_a, path_b):
  '''
  Measure the Earth Mover's distance between two images
  @args:
    {str} path_a: the path to an image file
    {str} path_b: the path to an image file
  @returns:
    TODO
  '''
  img_a = get_img(path_a, norm_exposure=True)
  img_b = get_img(path_b, norm_exposure=True)
  hist_a = get_histogram(img_a)
  hist_b = get_histogram(img_b)
  return wasserstein_distance(hist_a, hist_b)


def structural_sim(path_a, path_b):
  '''
  Measure the structural similarity between two images
  @args:
    {str} path_a: the path to an image file
    {str} path_b: the path to an image file
  @returns:
    {float} a float {-1:1} that measures structural similarity
      between the input images
  '''
  img_a = get_img(path_a)
  img_b = get_img(path_b)
  sim, diff = compare_ssim(img_a, img_b, full=True) # if 1 they are similar
  return sim


def pixel_sim(path_a, path_b):
  '''
  Measure the pixel-level similarity between two images
  @args:
    {str} path_a: the path to an image file
    {str} path_b: the path to an image file
  @returns:
    {float} a float {-1:1} that measures structural similarity
      between the input images
  '''
  img_a = get_img(path_a, norm_exposure=True)
  img_b = get_img(path_b, norm_exposure=True)
  return np.sum(np.absolute(img_a - img_b)) / float(height*width) / 255


def sift_sim(path_a, path_b):
  '''
  Use SIFT features to measure image similarity
  @args:
    {str} path_a: the path to an image file
    {str} path_b: the path to an image file
  @returns:
    TODO
  '''
  # initialize the sift feature detector
  orb = cv2.ORB()

  # get the images
  img_a = cv2.imread(path_a, 0)
  img_b = cv2.imread(path_b, 0)

  # find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
  kp_a, desc_a = orb.detectAndCompute(img_a, None)
  kp_b, desc_b = orb.detectAndCompute(img_b, None)

  # initialize the bruteforce matcher
  bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

  # match.distance is a float between {0:100} - lower means more similar
  matches = bf.match(desc_a, desc_b)
  similar_regions = [i for i in matches if i.distance < 70]
  if len(matches) == 0:
    return 0
  return len(similar_regions) / float(len(matches))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  img_a = 'sample/image1.png'
  img_b = 'sample/image2.png' #sample/087_GR_ALL_RS_036.png
  # get the similarity values
  structural_sim = structural_sim(img_a, img_b) # 1 is perfect structural similarity. A value of -1 indicates no structural similarity
  pixel_sim = pixel_sim(img_a, img_b) # 0 is similar
  sift_sim = sift_sim(img_a, img_b) # 1 is similar
  emd = earth_movers_distance(img_a, img_b) # 0.0 is similar
  print(structural_sim, pixel_sim, sift_sim, emd)
```

I am expecting the results in percentages such as 75%, 88%, 90%.

[EDIT] Consider image1 from https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJoPA.jpg
and consider image2 from https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWCdg.jpg

Comment: Without looking at the code, it is a bad idea in general to simply average different measurements. An intuitive reason for this would be because 1% increase in one metric and 1% increase in the other metric would lead to the same final increase, but does not necessarily produce the same impact. The simple answer is that you can't really have one number that measure all aspects of the similarity and be roboust metric.

Comment: Hello Paul92, so you mean to say it is not possible to compute a combined metric to compute percentage similarity.